# Post/Page editor loads twice

Tags: visual-editor, post-editor

WordPress 4.9.2

On the backend, the Page/Post editor seems to be loading twice. First it displays the **Text** version of the page/post. Then just when you think it finished, it reloads again with the **Visual** version.

My preference is Text as I speak HTML fluently, but I understand most users don't. Making this a user preference would be better than this double loading. This is really slowing down productivity.

Is anyone else observing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a normal behavior. Try to set default editor, and that should fix it. If it does not fix the problem, you may have one of your plugins causing it. Deactivate all plugins, and then reactivate them, one by one, until you find  one, which is responsible. Code below goes to `functions.php`:

Set default editor to **HTML**:

```
add_filter('wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "html";'));
```

Set default editor to **Visual**:

```
add_filter('wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "tinymce";'));
```

**Update**: the proper use of a closure, will be:

```
add_filter('wp_default_editor', function() { return 'tinymce'; } );
```

Comment: Note that `create_function()` has been deprecated in PHP 7.2. One should simply use `function() { return 'html'; }` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Setting the default editor is not a solution as I am only the webmaster and the clients likely have their own preferences. I guess checking which of their 30 plugins is the cause is the next step. To narrow it down I assume I'm looking for a plugin that interacts with the post/page editor?